# Flutter: App published in playstore not showing open button

Tags: flutter

I have build a flutter app and uploaded it to playstore. But after installing the app, it doesn't showing open button (showing only uninstall button).
The screenshot of the playstore is given below

[image: Screenshot of the app in playstore]

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, but when I **Clear Data** of the **PlayStore App** the error was Solved.

I think this is a **Temporary solution** but you can try it.